# node.js on express unable to find the model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a post method in my router file where I instantiated an object from Contact model. But I am getting undefined for Contact model. The error is

**Error:**

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined**
```

**routes/contact.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Contact = require("../models/contacts");

router.post('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
   res.send("POST method");
    newContact = new Contact({
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      lastname: req.body.lastname
   }
```

**models/contacts.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var contactSchema = new Schema({
  firstname:  String,
  lastname: String
});

var Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is correct. You have to use body-parser to parse the request body.

See :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples

Add following code in routes/contact.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
router.use(bodyParser.json())
```